# The width of my header and the wrapper/container below

Tags: html, css, header, width, wrapper

Can I get some help on making my full width header and top menus the same width as my main wrapper/container?

Here's a picture: http://soccer-mate.com/content/uploads/2017/07/IMG_1247.jpg

Here's what I have as custom CSS so far:

```
/* Structure */
#wrapper{ 
    min-height: 100%; 
    position: relative; 
    padding: 0.5px 0 20px; 
}
#main{ 
    padding: 10px 10px 0; 
}

/* Header */
#header{ 
    min-width: 990px; 
    padding: 0; 
}
#branding{ 
    width: 980px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 0; 
}
.logo{ 
    max-width: 590px; 
    float: left; 
    padding: 30px 0 34px 10px;
}
.blog-name{
    margin: 0 0 3px; 
    line-height: 1em; 
    display: block; 
}
.blog-description{ 
    line-height: 1em; 
    display: block; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 3px 0 0; 
}
#top-menu, #nav{ 
    min-width: 990px; 
}
#top-menu-content, #nav-content{ 
    margin: 0 auto; width: 978px;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

like this :

```
#wrapper                
{ width:100%;min-height: 100%; position: relative; padding: 0.5px 0 20px; }
```

Comment: Here's the original CSS

Comment: #main {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;}
#container {
    width:660px;
    float:left;
}
#content {
    margin:0;
    width:660px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.main-aside {
    width:300px;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
}
#secondary {
    clear:right;
}
#subsidiary {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#subsidiary .aside {
    width:300px;
    float:left;
    margin:0 20px 0 0;
}
#subsidiary #third {
    margin:0;
}
#main .module, #main .single-post {
 margin-right: 10px;
}
.fixed {
 width:960px;
}

Comment: /* Structure */
    #wrapper    { min-height: 100%; position: relative; padding: 20px 0; }
#main     { padding: 10px 10px 0; }

/* Header */
#header     { min-width: 990px; padding: 0; }
#branding    { width: 980px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; }
.logo     { max-width: 590px; float: left; padding: 30px 0 34px 10px; }
.blog-name    { margin: 0 0 3px; line-height: 1em; display: block; }
.blog-description  { line-height: 1em; display: block; margin: 0; padding: 3px 0 0; }